# axios.post get 500 error

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, axios

i'm trying to create a website chat app with laravel 5.4 and vue 2.0
I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aTfMHg3V1Q and everything working fine until I try to persist the message send with axios.post

My web.php:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'profile/{username}/you'], function()
{
Route::post('/privatechat/{id}', function(){
        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->send()->create([
            'chat_room'     =>  request()->segment(5),
            'message'       =>  request()->get('message'),
            'sender_id'     =>  Auth::user()->id,
            'receiver_id'   =>  request()->input('receiver')
        ]);

        return ['status' => 'OK'];
    })->middleware('auth');
 });
```

And my vue:

```
var url = location.href + '/' + $(this).val();
const app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    messages: [],
                    sendClass: 'chat-send'
                    //Điều kiện
                },
                methods: {
                    addMessage(message) {
                        this.messages.push(message);

                        axios.post(url, message)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            alert('Complete! Thanks for your message!');
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                    }
                },
                mounted() {
                    var u = url;
                    axios.get(u).then(response => {
                        //console.log(response);
                        this.messages = response.data;
                    });
                }
            });
```

And when I hit enter to send my message, this error show up in chrome console:

```
POST 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ app.js:11154
xhrAdapter @ app.js:10991
dispatchRequest @ app.js:11633
```

Where is my code wrong?

Comment: Is the CSRF token added to the request? Do you have an error description from the network tab in your browser or the Laravel log file?

Comment: I'm not sure, I saw this code in bootstrap.js

`window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};`

Does this mean X-CSRF-TOKEN include in my request?

Comment: Yes, that should be good enough. Did you check the log / network tab in your browser?

Comment: @piscator please check my answer below

Comment: `Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' in /home/vagrant/website/hgc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illum‌​inate/Database/Conne‌​ction.php:449`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new Chat (new entry), if I am not wrong, can you do this without send method? Just Chat::create... Because you first retrieve chat, which already has ID, and then inserting same Chat with already used id is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

I use laravel-log-viewer and see this:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' 
in /home/vagrant/website/hgc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:449
```

Comment: Can you post laravel error? Network, then click on this request (load response). This should display laravel error explanation.

Comment: I think send() can be problem. Try without chaining. Also, you didnt post any error.

Comment: @Tim and send come from my User model

`public function send()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Chat','id');
    }`

Comment: I post again my error

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' 
in /home/vagrant/website/hgc/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:449`

Comment: You are creating new Chat (new entry), if I am not wrong, can you do this without send method? Just Chat::create...Because you first retrieve chat, which already has ID, and then inserting same Chat with already used id isn not going to work.

Comment: @Tim unbelievable :(( Thanks Tim, now everything work like a charm!!! You save my day :D

Comment: Glad to help. You can also do this with relationship ([laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)) insert (no need for manually setting user_id field) but it works either way. Please mark as answered.